# InvalidSlotTypeLiteral: Slot type "AMAZON.LITERAL" for slot "Text" in intent "RawText" is not valid

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

`AMAZON.LITERAL` is deprecated as of October 22, 2018. Older skills built with `AMAZON.LITERAL`.

What is the alternative to `AMAZON.LITERAL`, I want each and every word spoken by user from Alexa device in my endpoint API.

I have created custom slots, but my endpoint is not called everytime.

Anyone have solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

**You will not get the entire user input** through any inbuilt slots or intents. The closest one to your requirement that I can think of is `AMAZON.SearchQuery`.

### AMAZON.SearchQuery

`AMAZON.SearchQuery` is a **phrase-type slot** that lets you capture less-predictable input that makes up the search query.   You can use phrase slots when you cannot predict all possible values the user might say, or when there may not be an identifiable pattern that can be captured by a custom slot. The intended use of this slot is to capture short messages, comments, search queries, and other short free-form text, **not the entire user spoken utterance.**

Ex:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "SearchIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Query",
          "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery"
        },
        {
          "name": "CityList",
          "type": "AMAZON.US_CITY"
        }
      ],
      "samples": [
        "search for {Query} near me",
        "find out {Query}",
        "search for {Query}",
        "give me details about {CityList}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**You cannot add sample intent utterances consisting of only phrase type slots.** 
That means, you cannot give something like this:

```
{
   "name": "QueryIntent",
      "slots": [
         {
            "name": "query",
            "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery"
         }
       ],
   "samples": [
      "{query}"   // utterance with only phrase-type slot
   ]
}
```

More on `AMAZON.SearchQuery` [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery)

---

Alexa will always will fire a `POST` request to your skill's endpoint with a payload whenever there is a user interaction.

Comment: i am not getting value in my enpoint url 
"whatever user is speaking on alexa device"

Comment: is your endpoint not called everytime or you are not getting any value from the request?

Comment: its called only twice 
i am not getting query value.

without value my api will not respond properly

Comment: are you getting the query value in the request JSON while testing in test console

Comment: request: 
      { type: 'IntentRequest',
        requestId: 'amzn1.echo-api.request.a56d9c4a-a90a-4898-b12f-ecc9928a1ece',
        timestamp: '2018-11-21T13:21:10Z',
        locale: 'en-US',
        intent: 
         { name: 'SearchIntent',
           confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
           slots: 
            { Query: { name: 'Query', confirmationStatus: 'NONE' },
              CityList: { name: 'CityList', confirmationStatus: 'NONE' } } } } }

Their is no value in this request

Comment: What I have given is an example of how it can be done. Do not just copy paste it.

Comment: But my question is anything user speaks should be detected not based on sample uttrance

Comment: There are no  predefined slots or intents that will capture the entire user utterance. Check my updated answer

Comment: in AMAZON.LITERAL, i was getting entire text